# SharePoint - Remote machine shows wrong design

Tags: css, sharepoint, master-pages

I am creating a SharePoint public website on SharePoint Server 2007.

I've added my custom Master-page for Publishing site.

When I see, Home page, on my local machine, in the content area of my page it shows me IMAGE on the right as I want to see.

But, When I see that page on my remote machine It shows my IMAGE on the left, instead of right side.

I'm using following layout:

```
<div id="Content">
   <div id="left">
   </div>
   <div id="right">
        **--->>>I've IMAGE over here..!!!!**
   </div>
</div>
```

Can Anyone help me how to resolve this problem.

Thanks.

Comment: What browser are you using in each case? The CSS targeting those elements would also be important in diagnosing the problem.

Comment: I'm using IE-8 on both machine.

Answer (score 0):

Without more information it's hard to tell what's your problem, but here is a couple of common issues:

1. Non approved versions of files. But if you're logging in as the same user then that's not the problem
2. Cached css. If your browser has ever retrieved an old version of the css (and you haven't renamed that) then it'll have the old version cached. CTRL+F5 will solve the problem if that's the case. But then all your users will have to do that if they got the old version cached.